# Debug appengine on localhost:8888 SSL issue

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, ssl

I am trying to create a facebook app for my appengine (java) website.
First of all, I'll really appreciate if someone found good example of doing so (facebook app) while using Struts2 on appengine.

anyway, while creating the app on facebook I saw that I have to specify a "Secure Canvas URL".
I used:

```
https://localhost:8888/enter?
```

but when calling the app url, I keep getting this error:

```
Secure Connection Failed An error occurred during a connection to
localhost:8888. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum
permissible length. (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

I tried to navigate to the same url on localhost (not through facebook) same error,
then, I tried to deploy the code to my appengine and run the url (not through facebook) and it WORKS.

I still want to be able to DEBUG my code, while writing the facebook auth etc. so if you got any idea how I can debug SSL\HTTPS on my local computer, please HELP!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out i can change facebooks default ''secured'' behaviuor and let it redirect to apps using regular http requests.
Saved my day...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Facebook still supports disabling SSL so this answer is no longer valid...

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can!  You'll have to generate yourself some self signed SSL keys to install on your server.  Once you have done that you'll have to make sure that your server is accepting requests over a secured SSL connection (using `https` instead of `http`).

For local development this is fine, you just have to accept the self signed certificate in your browser (ever time you open it) but for production code [you are required to purchase an SSL certificate](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/499/) for your domain.

Comment: I am running my server on google appengine. not sure how to set such things on it\ if it is even possible... as I wrote, production appengine is OK (SSL works fine) - it is onl the development environment....